# Android: Dialog return spinners to host

Tags: android, android-dialog

So I need to have a dialog box where a user can select year/month (for credit cards). When the user click OK to the dialog, the host (i.e the activity that created the dialog) should be notified about the changes.

I need the application to work on SDK version 7 and therefore i cannot use DialogFragment as suggested here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Currently this is what I got:

```
public class DatePicker {

    /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
    public interface DatePickerListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(int month, int year);
        public void onDialogNegativeClick();
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    static DatePickerListener mListener;

    public static void show(Activity listner) {
        mListener = (DatePickerListener)listner;
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity)mListener);
        LayoutInflater inflater = listner.getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker, null))
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(11, 11);
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                   }
               }


            );  
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }

}
```

and the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerMonth"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerYear"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So I have two problems: The first one is that i cannot seem to get the spinners value in the onClick dialogs, and secondly I need to set the spinners contents programmatically and I cant seem to figure out how to do that either (as I cant seem to get the dialogs content properly).

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every single credit card implementation I ever saw, on a phone, computer, or anywhere, has all elements in a single window. Are you sure you want to change the experience users most probably expect, to one involving a popup dialog?

Wouldn't it be simpler for both you and them, if the activity itself had all the necessary inputs: a textfield for the credit card number, two spinners for the day and month, and a CVS textfield - it's not as if it would make you run out of space, even on a small screen mobile.

Whether you are deadset on your idea or not, the answer remains the same, something like this:

```
class something {
  int mMonth;
  int mDay;
  (...)
monthSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    mMonth = pos;   
  }
  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
});
```

Comment: This flow have been requested by the customer. The problem is that I cannot seem to properly get the monthSpinner view anywhere in the show method.